# How to filter new work items from notifications?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working in Azure DevOps and have a notification query set to alert me when an iteration path or area path is changed. Unfortunately anytime a new item is created, it is viewed as changed. I need to refine this query to disclude "New" items.

The Notifications Query fields/operators and values are not as expansive as they are when building a regular query (Boards > Queries).

Here is the query:

[Notifications Query in Azure DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6507.jpg)

Ideally the results of this query would only be changes to existing items, but no new items.

Comment: Have you tried Pero P.'s reply? Did it work out?

Comment: I have but haven't been able to verify it works -- I've not forgotten. Oddly enough, there hasn't been any new items added (as we're nearing end of sprint). But once I can validate it, I'll be back.

Comment: Just verified a new item -- which did NOT come in. Selecting the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following filter criteria:

`Rev > 1`

New work items are created with a `Rev` of `1` and subsequent modifications will increment that rev/revision/version number.